# UnsupportedClassVersion error while trying to run simple Java code

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile my programs using the command prompt on Windows 7. I'm having a problem when I during compile. I created a test program:

```
class test
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("this is working!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

I use the following instructions from the command line:

```
cd \ 
cd summer
Javac test.java 
java test
```

I have even tried using javaw and I get the same message but in a pop-up box

> Could not find the main class, program will exit.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you have a JRE installed that has an older version than the JDK you have. Make sure your "java.exe" comes from the same installation as your "javac.exe".

Comment: @BhavikAmban i am trying to compile test.java but i get the "message could not find the main class"

Comment: Can you edit your question with the results of running `java -version` and `javac -version`?

Comment: ive managed to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using different versions of JDK. Check the versions on your javac vs java. This error is telling you that your java and compiled class are not same versions. Check your path for configuration, type "set" in dos to see details.

Example: If you compiled your class with javac (version 7) and execute it with java (version 6)

Comment: Compiling with 6 and running with 7 should work. The other way around (compiling with 7, running with 6) does not. That's probably what's happening in this case.

Answer (score 5):

It seems your JDK and JVM have different editions.

Comment: This should be comment rather then an answer.

Comment: He doesn't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: @SenthilKumar that's not an excuse to abuse the answering system. That said, this isn't a terrible answer. It's not great, but it's only been three minutes.

Comment: It's an answer. I don't know why it is regarded as a comment.

Comment: This is an answer. How much more could he elaborate this point?